# Unable to locate/populate Text box in Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

```html
<TD class=CuteEditorFrameContainer style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-TOP: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px" height="100%" colSpan=2>
<IFRAME id=obj_oOpera class=CuteEdit style="BORDER-TOP: #c0c0c0 1px solid; HEIGHT: 100%; BORDER-RIGHT: #c0c0c0 1px solid; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-BOTTOM: #c0c0c0 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #c0c0c0 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white"  frameBorder=0>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE>BODY {
 PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY contentEditable=true>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</IFRAME>
<INPUT id=oOpera type=hidden name=oOpera>
</TD>
```

**Problem** 
I am trying to populate comment box but not able to due to following issues

-- Inspecting box takes me to code where there are no attributes - **BODY contentEditable=true**

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('obj_oOpera')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='obj_oOpera']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='obj_oOpera']")).sendKeys("Opera");

-- When I use Attributes from **IFRAME or INPUT** tags throws exception **Element must not be hidden/read-only or disabled**

**Other Methods that did not work**
change of frame. 
Java Script and 
usual Send Keys

**PS** - I am able to maually add text to Text-box

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to enter a value in input but you are passing the id of the iframe. Simply replace it the input id and your issue will be solved.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('oOpera')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='oOpera']")).clear(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='oOpera']")).sendKeys("Opera");
```

Also, your input field is outside of Iframe and body inside Iframe has no element in it that's why it is showing empty body.

Comment: Perfect solution but I suspect if _id_ or _name_ would be unique. However the premise provided, this solution should nail the OP.

Comment: Thank you for reply Waqar

But I am getting Error message - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must not be read-only or disabled